# Leaflet js map popup filtering

Tags: leaflet

I have a map with city popups in Leaflet js. Is there a way to filter the cities, so that I can click on the filter option on the map, so they show me only cities from a specific province, and hide the other cities?

```
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: auto; height: 1500px"></div>
    <script>
        // Creating map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: [46.7986771, 19.6500625],
            zoom: 6
        }

        // Creating a map object
        var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);

        // Creating a Layer object
        var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

        // Adding layer to the map
        map.addLayer(layer);


        var greenIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
            shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            shadowSize: [41, 41]
        });

        function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
            return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
        }

        fetch('/api/points').then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
            data.forEach(function(element) {
                let popupHtml = `
                <section>
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr>
                                <hr>
        <h3 align="center">${capitalizeFirstLetter(element.province)}</h3><h3 align="center">${element.city}</h3> <h3 align="center">
        <img class = "foto" src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593818681410-e7b0b567d036?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100" alt="live"/><br>
        <a href="${element.link}" target="_blank"> Link</a> </h3><hr></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
            `;

                L.marker([element.lat, element.lng], {
                    icon: greenIcon
                }).bindPopup(popupHtml).addTo(map);
            });
        });    </script>
```

This is the code I have

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data again for actuality you could do this:

```html
fetch('/api/points').then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
            data.forEach(function(element) {
            if(element.city == 'dramcity') {
                let popupHtml = `
                <section>
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr>
                                <hr>
        <h3 align="center">${capitalizeFirstLetter(element.province)}</h3><h3 align="center">${element.city}</h3> <h3 align="center">
        <img class = "foto" src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593818681410-e7b0b567d036?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100" alt="live"/><br>
        <a href="${element.link}" target="_blank"> Link</a> </h3><hr></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
            `;

                L.marker([element.lat, element.lng], {
                    icon: greenIcon
                }).bindPopup(popupHtml).addTo(map);
                }
            });
        });
```

if you dont want to fetch again, put your response.json() in a variable and itarate

```js
var resp = fetch('/api/points').then(response => {
  return response.json()
})

for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
  if (resp.city == 'expected') {
    let popupHtml = `
            <section>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                            <hr>
    <h3 align="center">${capitalizeFirstLetter(resp.province)}</h3><h3 align="center">${resp.city}</h3> <h3 align="center">
    <img class = "foto" src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593818681410-e7b0b567d036?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100" alt="live"/><br>
    <a href="${resp.link}" target="_blank"> Link</a> </h3><hr></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        `;

    L.marker([resp.lat, resp.lng], {
      icon: greenIcon
    }).bindPopup(popupHtml).addTo(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice that this code is not running on a button click. you can do this easy with putting all this into a function and then call this function on onclick.

Comment: how can I turn this into a function onclick?

Comment: This Example should help you ;) : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick